# How can I tell if Elastic Beanstalk is running my config files?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm getting an error on my deployed application:

`Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'ebdb.users' doesn't exist`

This leads me to believe my `php artisan migrate` command isn't working, and the `users` table isn't being created.

This is one of my config files (in my .elasticbeanstalk folder)

```
container_commands:
    00testCommand:
        command: "echo test"
    01migrateSeed:
        command: "php artisan migrate --force"
    02seed: 
        command: "php artisan db:seed --force"
```

This is my create users migration file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('referral_id')->unique();
            $table->string('referred_by')->nullable()->default(null);
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

Am I missing something obvious? Is this error not related to my migration? I'd like to know if these commands are even being run, but can't find them in the Elastic Beanstalk environment log.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

move the config file to the `.ebextensions` folder. it does not belong to the `.elasticbeanstalk` one

Comment: I don't have this folder - can I just create it or is there a specific command that I should be using?